# Internet Explorer ignoring all "0" characters in JS file

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, gwt, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

This is an issue I have been dealing with for months, and I would really appreciate any help.

I am encoding a string and writing the output to MyFile.js using the function below. While debugging my example, `char encodedCode[]` displayed as integers has `length 12` and these values: `97,0,108,101,114,116,40,34,80,114,0,105`.

MyFile.js is correctly generated with the expected size and characters, as I can see from Notepad++.

**MyFileServlet.java**

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
throws ServletException, IOException
{
    res.setCharacterEncoding("iso-8859-1");
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/javascript;charset=iso-8859-1");
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=MyFile.js");
    PrintWriter printer=res.getWriter();
    char encodedCode[]=encode(req.getParameter("originalScript"));
    printer.write(encodedCode);
    printer.close();
}
```

However, when I try to run that MyFile.js with some debugging code (see below) from MyFile.html, I get different behaviour depending on the browser:

- **Chrome/Firefox:** `length 12` values `97,0,108,101,114,116,40,34,80,114,0,105`
- **Internet Explorer 9:** `length 10` values `97,108,101,114,116,40,34,80,114,105`

So **IE is ignoring all the "0" characters**. Why? Thank you very much

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/vnqL2/

**Edit:** I tried writing those bytes to an external binary file MyFile.xxx and reading them from Javascript/JQuery/Ajax/XMLHttpRequest and I still get the same issue with IE.

**MyFile.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="iso-8859-1" src="MyFile.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**MyFile.js**

```
function d(a)
{
  a=(a+"").split("");
  var l=a.length,x=[l];
  alert(l);
  for(i=0;i<l;i++){
    x[i]=a[i].charCodeAt(0);
    document.write(x[i]);
  }
};
d("HERE GO THOSE BYTES HARDCODED");
```

Comment: BTW, setting up a http://jsfiddle.net/ that displays the bug is handy for this sort of question

Comment: Done! But unfortunately I cannot hardcode some characters there (see comments)

Comment: How is `"HERE GO THOSE BYTES HARDCODED"` being populated? I wouldn't expect embedding a null character inside a javascript string literal to work very well.

Comment: In MyFileServlet.java those characters are written on MyFile.js exactly where "HERE GO THOSE BYTES HARDCODED". Should I try to write them to another binary file MyFile.xxx and read this from Javascript?

Comment: I just tried writing those bytes from an external binary file MyFile.xxx, reading this from Javascript/JQuery/Ajax/XMLHttpRequest and I still get the same issue with IE.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem in IE9 - running the jsFiddle gives me the same results in all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what is your purpose but NULL bytes inside strings are not legit.

On the other hand you could easily reconstruct an array of bytes (integers) by transmitting the bytes as a comma seperated list of integers. Or another approach would be a json file.
Example code:

```
function d(a)
{
  a=(a+"").split(",");
  var l=a.length,x=[l];
  alert(l);
  for(i=0;i<l;i++){
    x[i]=Number(a[i]);
    document.write(x[i]);
    document.write("<br>");
  }
  return x;
};
var ar = d("97,0,108,101,114,116,40,34,80,114,0,105"); // returns the byte array, length=12
```

[Test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/vnqL2/1/)